# svn commit from bash script without opening the editor

Tags: bash, svn, commit

I try to write a bash script which should commit to a svn repo. Everything works fine until the point where I try to commit. The commit command opens the editor and the script ends with an error that the commit message was left in `svn-commit.tmp`

I try a couple of things but none will work

```
commit_msg="$1"
svn commit -m "$commit_msg"
```

and

```
commit_msg="$1"
svn commit -m '$commit_msg'
```

and

```
commit_msg=$1
svn commit -m '$commit_msg'
```

and all with the `-q` and `--non-interactive`operators. Even `svn commit -m "woohoo"` opens the editor and the script ends with the error.

Any ideas why it is impossible to commit within a bash script without opening the editor?

Comment: Does the editor also open if you run `svn commit -m "..."` from command line?

Comment: No, only if I use `svn commit` in a bash script.

Comment: What do you get from `type svn`?

Comment: Can you provide the exact script you are using (or at least a portion of it up to the `svn commit` call that fails)?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the --non-interactive option on the svn command:

```
svn commit --non-interactive -m '$commit_msg'
```

Comment: My english is very bad, I know. But "... and all with the -q and --non-interactive operators" could be a hint that I already tried it. Sorry, no success.

Answer (score 1):

After I tried `svn ci` instead of `svn commit`, everything was fine. My first thought was a buggy version of svn. Asking the Great Dump (aka Google) I found the solution:: In my .bash_profile was a code snippt that forced the `svn commit` always to open the editor while `svn ci` worked as expected.

I don't know exactly where the code snippet came from, but  windows users have to fight a lot of mysterious behaviours.

Thanks all for your help.